# ViewHolder with onClicklistener Issue with UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, android-viewholder, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm a beginner so please bare with me.

I have a viewholder that has an onclicklistener.

The aim of the click is to send a Url string into another fragment using Jetpack Navigation (hopefully i did it right)

the Url is being created within the dataclass itself.

but i keep getting this error:

`kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property galleryItem has not been initialized`

I tried working around using companion object and other ways, nothing worked... is there a solution for this?

here is the view holder and data class

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import androidx.core.os.bundleOf
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.paging.PagingDataAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.saheralsous.android.R
import com.saheralsous.android.database.remote.model.PagingData

class RecyclerViewPhotoAdapter() :
    PagingDataAdapter<PagingData.GalleryItem, PhotoHolder>(
        diffCallback = DiffCallback
    ) {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PhotoHolder, position: Int) {
        getItem(position)?.let {
            holder.bind(it)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PhotoHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.photo_item_view,parent,false)
        return PhotoHolder(view)
    }
}

class PhotoHolder(view: View):
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
    
    private val imageButtom: ImageButton = view.findViewById(R.id.ImageButton)
    private lateinit var galleryItem: PagingData.GalleryItem //page. 594


    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    fun bind(galleryItem : PagingData.GalleryItem){
        /*
        idTextView.text = galleryItem.id
        ownerTextView.text = galleryItem.owner
        titleTextView.text = galleryItem.title
        urlTextView.text = galleryItem.url
         */
        galleryItem.url.let { url ->
            Glide.with(itemView)
                .load(url)
                .override(350,350)
                .into(imageButtom)
        }
    }

    init {
        imageButtom.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        println("item was clicked")
        val bundle = bundleOf("url" to galleryItem.photoPageUri )  <-- here is the issue
        Navigation.findNavController(v!!).navigate(
            R.id.action_photoGalleryFragment_to_photoPageFragment,
            bundle)
    }
}




object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<PagingData.GalleryItem>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: PagingData.GalleryItem, newItem: PagingData.GalleryItem): Boolean {
        // Id is unique.
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: PagingData.GalleryItem, newItem: PagingData.GalleryItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

data class

```
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.annotation.Keep
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class PagingData(
    val total : Int =0,
    val Page: Int = 0,
    val photos : List<GalleryItem>
){
    val endOfPage = total == Page

    @Keep
    data class GalleryItem(
        @SerializedName("id")
        val id: String,
        @SerializedName("owner")
        val owner: String,
        @SerializedName("title")
        var title: String,
        @SerializedName("url_s")
        val url: String) {
        val photoPageUri : Uri <-- here is the value
            get() {
                return Uri.parse("https://www.flickr.com/photos/")
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendPath(owner)
                    .appendPath(id)
                    .build()
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you haven't initialised the galleryItem instance variable in your PhotoHolder.  Add this inside your `bind` method:

```
this.galleryItem = galleryItem
```